# How can we save a Tensorflow model made from a contrib.learn.Classifier?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to save a model made from contrib.learn.Classifier but I don't know how to get to refer to its internal nodes. This is the code that I use in a vanilla Tensorflow model (y=W*x+b), and it works great.

```
W = tf.Variable([], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([], dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="x")
my_model = tf.add(W * x, b, name="model")
...  # training
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("/tmp/saved_model")
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ["predict_tag"], signature_def_map= {
          "model": tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
              inputs= {"x": x},
              outputs= {"model": my_model})
          })
builder.save()
```

Now if I use contrib.learn.Classifier

```
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)
estimator.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000)
```

How can I use the `builder` above similarly for this latter `estimator` ? Note that I DONT want to do `tf.train.Saver().save(sess, "/tmp/model")` ; using the `saved_model.builder` is a requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `export_savedmodel` function of the estimator that exports inference graph as a SavedModel into given dir., [`tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LinearClassifier)

```
from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers import feature_column as feature_column_lib
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.utils.input_fn_utils import build_parsing_serving_input_fn

# create feature specs from feature columns
feature_spec = feature_column_lib.create_feature_spec_for_parsing(
  feature_columns)

# create the input function 
serving_input_fn = build_parsing_serving_input_fn(feature_spec)

# finally save the model
estimator.export_savedmodel('/path/to/save/my_model/', serving_input_fn=input_receiver_fn)
```